# Scenario for using deja-dup for restoration

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-mate, deja-dup

I use deja-dup and Clonezilla for backups.

What scenario would there be where deja-dup would be used to restore?

Comment: That's a rather open-ended question that Stack Exchange considers unsuitable for its Q&A format. Could you please try narrow it down a little? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Backups archive files in case a disk or any other device that contains a file system fails.  This could be a media or hardware error on the disk, or in very rare circumstances, file system corruption caused by an OS problem.

Another common scenario is user error, such as the mistaken deletion of a precious directory or file using `rm` or possibly overwriting.

A final class of failures is the inadvertent loss or destruction of the machine.  You can use your backups to rebuild your computer with the same files as the original.  So keep your backup volumes in a different location.

Kernel panics are uncommon and are very unlikely to result in file system corruption or failure, although it can happen.

Comment: I keep my backup volumes on a separate hard drive.

Comment: Me too.  And encrypted in the cloud.